# increase number when I press arrow key on keyboard with javascript

Tags: javascript, increment, arrow-keys

I have a textbox has a numeric value. 
now what I want is to keep increasing that numeric value while im pressing and holding any of arrow keys. 
I know how to do this if I was pressing only one time. it will be increased by 1 only. but what If I want to keep increasing the value while i'm holding the arrow keys. how to do that?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

There's a small jQuery plugin for doing this:
https://github.com/nakupanda/number-updown

Usages:

```
$('#simplest').updown();
```

$('#step').updown({
    step: 10,
    shiftStep: 100
});

$('#minMax').updown({
    min: -10,
    max: 10
});

$('#minMaxCircle').updown({
    min: -10,
    max: 10,
    circle: true
});

View live demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/XCtaH/embedded/result/

Keyboard and mousewheel events supporte

Answer (score 1):

This is not fully tried and tested by me, but here is a thought - You might want to track KeyDown events because that's the event which is queued by the OS when the key is first pressed. You might also want to implement some sort of delay when incrementing this way so as not to overwhelm the client-side script and have numbers change at a speed to high for user to track.

Comment: `onkeydown` will indeed work, and it won't be "overwhelmingly" fast in any case - keys will only repeat at the rate set in the OS settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about supporting Opera, this is easy:

```
textbox.onkeydown = function(e)
{
    if (e.keyCode == 38)
    {
        incrementTextBox();
    }
}
```

However, Opera doesn't fire `keydown` for key repeats... you'll have to mimic that by calling `incrementTextBox()` at an interval, and stopping when the key is lifted.  I tested this in WebKit (Chrome 6.0), FF3, Opera 10.6, IE7, IE8, IE9, even IE Quirks:

```
var textbox = null;
window.onload = function()
{
    var timeoutId = null;
    var intervalId = null;
    var incrementRepeatStarted = false;
    function startIncrementKeyRepeat()
    {
        timeoutId = window.setTimeout(function()
        {
            intervalId = window.setInterval(incrementTextBox, 50);
        }, 300);
    }
    function abortIncrementKeyRepeat()
    {
        window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        window.clearInterval(intervalId);
        timeoutId = null;
        intervalId = null;
    }
    function endIncrementKeyRepeat()
    {
        abortIncrementKeyRepeat();
        incrementRepeatStarted = false;
    }
    textbox = document.getElementById("incrementer");
    textbox.onkeydown = function(e)
    {
        e = e || window.event;
        if (e.keyCode == 38)
        {
            if (!incrementRepeatStarted)
            {
                startIncrementKeyRepeat();
                incrementRepeatStarted = true;
            }
            else if (timeoutId || intervalId)
            {
                abortIncrementKeyRepeat();
            }
            incrementTextBox();
        }
        else if (incrementRepeatStarted)
        {
            endIncrementKeyRepeat();
        }
    }
    textbox.onkeyup = endIncrementKeyRepeat;
}
function incrementTextBox()
{
    var val = parseInt(textbox.value) || 0;
    val++;
    textbox.value = val;
}
```

Comment: That's what I get for not testing my own answer.  But, it works in Opera!  :)  I'll edit my answer with corrections.

Answer (score 0):

ok after some tests I made here is how its done:

```
var setTimeoutId; 
var keyIs = "up"; 

 function myIncrementFunction()
    {
            var num = parseFloat(myText.value)+1;
            myText.value = num; 

    }

myText.onkeydown = function(e)
    {
    keyIs = "down";

    if(keyIs == "down")
        {
            var e = e || event ;
            if (e.keyCode == 38)
                {    
                    for(var s=0; s<1; s++)
                        setTimeoutId = setTimeout('myIncrementFunction()',100); 
                }
        }
    }

myText.onkeyup = function(e)
{ 
    keyIs = "up"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do this, i just used input field with type="number"